# Removing entries of a list that are also in another list

Tags: java

I have two lists, list A and List B, list A has some entries that are also in list B. Now I want to remove those entries from List B that are also in A, Can anybody tell me an efficient way to do this in Java ?

Comment: Only if you _reveal_ the not-so-efficient way that you tried.

Comment: Iterate on it and remove them.

Comment: iterate the list d use remove method

Comment: `listB.removeAll(listA)` ? That method can easily be found by browsing the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: show some effort please.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`List#removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) method:

> Removes from this list all of its elements
>   that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++)
{
   int index = -1;
   for(int j = i; i < listB.size(); j++)
      if(listA.get(i).equals(listB.get(j))
         index = j;

    if(index >= 0)
      listB.remove(index);

}
```